# IllegalArgumentException Base64 to image decoding android

Tags: android, bitmap, base64, decode, illegalargumentexception

I want to decode an image from webservice which is in base64 to the bitmap and use it in my android app. 
This is my method:

```
public Bitmap getCaptcha() throws IOException
    { 

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String json = jsonParser.getCaptcha(captchaURL, params);
        Log.i("", json);

         byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(json.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
         Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
         return bitmap;

    }
```

If I decode the string which I get from getCaptcha method with my php script - it displays correctly. But when I do this in my application, I get an

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.assignmentexpert/com.assignmentexpert.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
    at com.library.UserFunctions.getCaptcha(UserFunctions.java:97)
    at com.assignmentexpert.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:66)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    ... 11 more
```

What's is reason of it?

I add base64 code that I get:

```
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n
```

Problem is that when I copy the code from the browser and hardcode it to my program - everything works fine. But when I get the base64 data via my android program and try to hardcode the base64  - I get an exception. Code, which is in browser and what I get via Android looks the same. But, practically, it doesn't because of different result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the padding of your Base64 code is not good (wrong number of trailing `=` signs at the end of your code). For example, the base64 code corresponding to `Hello` is `SGVsbG8=`, and the last `=` is just there to make the size of the base64 data chunck compliant with the [Base64 RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt). So `SGVsbG8==` and `SGVsbG8` are both incorrect as the length of the chunck 
 is not according to the base64 spec, even though they both mean `Hello` if we stick to relevant characters (the "Base 64 Alphabet").

Some implementations are quite permissive about that. They just assume that a base64 chunck of an incorrect length needs padding with one or two "=". Some other, including Android, are not permissive, so the kind of discrepancy you are facing between the behaviours of your PHP and Android programs.

This is only an assumption, as I cannot see the base64 data you are trying to decode. To check that, you can use [this online base64 decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/), which will tell you whether the padding is ok.

Anyhow it would be easier with a sample of your base64 code. Would you add that to your post? I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is a `n` after the trailing `=` at the end of your code. This makes the base64 data chunck invalid. Once deleted, the rest is valid, I could decode it with no problem. Maybe the problem comes from your service. It seems a `\n` line termination character was erroneously mistyped `n` in the service code.

Comment: EEEEEEEEEEEEEE!!!!!thank you very much!!!!!!how could you identify this??? I wonder - what's the reason of this? web service send data correctly - because it shows correctly in the browser...why this "n" appeat at my client side? I send request and should recieve the same data...but it's not...very weird...thank you a lot...

Comment: You are welcome :) Maybe the mistake is in your Android client, which attempts to add a `\n` to the data it reads. Anyway, I'm just guessing, but let me know :)

Comment: the problem is not in \n but only in n...Client adds n as a last symbol...exluding it from the string data from the webservice solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! I guess we can close this question, then.

Answer (score 7):

Actually there is a simple solution to this which will remove any bad data after a valid base64 string:

```
String[] safe = received.split("=");
//put all chars before first base64 '=' padding char into safe[0]

try {
     byte[] recvpicbyte = Base64.decode(safe[0], Base64.NO_PADDING);
     //decode safe [0], note not in 'DEFUALT', use 'NO_PADDING' so it wont expect the '='

     //...do whatever with output
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in adding to JSON response an "n" character in the end of the base64 string of the image. The reason of it appereance is mystically. Interesting that other JSON response from that webservice come without "n" character. I tried to get that string of base64 image with regular Java code - everything was good - without "n" character. So it appereance due to android client - side. Try to investigate reason of its appereance and way to prevent it.
Thanks to [Shlublu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840960/shlublu) for his huge help!!!